# how to use shinyDirButton from shinyFiles inside a miniPage?

Tags: r, shiny

Please have a look at this code :

```
#' @import shiny
#' @import miniUI
#' @export
test <- function(numCols = 3) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyFiles)
  library(miniUI)
  volumes <- c('R Installation'=R.home())
  ui <- miniPage(style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",scrollable = TRUE,
                 gadgetTitleBar(span(strong("Granola"))),
                 wellPanel(id = "tPanel",
                           style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",
                             shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload"),
                             verbatimTextOutput("dir"),
                             uiOutput("fileSelect")
                 )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    library(shiny)
  }

  viewer <- shiny::dialogViewer("test", width = 800, height = 700)
  shiny::runGadget(shiny::shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = viewer,
                   stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}
test()
```

the popup inside the gadget dont allow the user to click on the "select" button.

[image: miniui and shinyfolder]

Do you have any idea how I can manage tu allow scrolling , or moving the popup ?

Regards

Comment: I temporaly edit the Shinyfile.js to remove the "content" part..

Comment: btw you have 2 shiny objects with the same id. Pretty sure that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal dialog built by `shinyFiles` inherits from the `.modal` bootstrap class that has `overflow: hidden`, you can overwrite this with

```r
tags$style( "#dir-modal{ overflow: scroll ; }", type = "text/css" )
```

somewhere in your ui code, or perhaps:

```r
tags$style( ".sF-modalContainer{ overflow: scroll ; }", type = "text/css" )
```

Otherwise you can create your own modified version of `shinyDirButton` to make the change for you.

```r
shinyDirButton <- function(id, ...){
  x <- shinyFiles::shinyDirButton(id, ...)
  x[[1]]$children <- append( 
    x[[1]]$children, 
    list( tags$style(glue("#{id}-modal{{ overflow: scroll; }}")) )  
  )
  x
}
```

So that you don't have to manually track the css class of all your `shinyDirButton`. Here is my full code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(miniUI)
library(glue)

my <- list( shinyDirButton = function(id, ...){
  x <- shinyFiles::shinyDirButton(id, ...)
  x[[1]]$children <- append( 
    x[[1]]$children, 
    list( tags$style(glue("#{id}-modal{{ overflow: scroll; }}")) )  
  )
  x
} )

test <- function(numCols = 3) {

  volumes <- c('R Installation'=R.home())
  ui <- miniPage(
    style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",
    scrollable = TRUE,

    gadgetTitleBar(span(strong("Granola"))),
    wellPanel(id = "tPanel",
      my$shinyDirButton("vfzzfz", "Chose directory", "Upload"),
      verbatimTextOutput("dir"),
      uiOutput("fileSelect")
    )

  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

  }

  viewer <- shiny::dialogViewer("test", width = 800, height = 700)
  shiny::runGadget(shiny::shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = viewer,
    stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}

test()
```